# How to get navigation menu under header image?

Tags: css, html

i have a header image and i want to come under the header image and i am making a responsive design so please help me i can figure out how to do this instead of doing this mess

```
nav {
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
    left:400px;
}
```

i want my nav and header image look like this

```
---------Header Image---------------------------------------------------------------------
'                                                                                        '
'                     Home | How to | About | Contact                                    '
'                                                                                        '
'                                                                                        '
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please Help me to do this and so that i can make it responsive too

Thanks in Advance